# Working with multiple tabs with python-socketio and socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, python-socketio, socket.io-client

At times, when we simultaneously open multiple tabs in different browsers or incognito sessions with the same logged-in user, the newly opened tabs can successfully send and receive messages. However, the older tabs do not send or receive messages, even though they remain connected to Python Socket.IO and socket.io-client. Additionally, I've already used a room session for managing the connections.
This Problem happens on a live server, not in local.

Here is my code.

```
python-socketio==5.9.0
uvicorn==0.16.0
eventlet==0.33.3
socket.io-client = 4.7.2
```

Server-side code:

```py
import socketio
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode="asgi", cors_allowed_origins='*', logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
connected_users = {}
room_user_count = {}
@sio.on("connect")
async def connect(sid, environ):
  try:
    query_string = environ.get("QUERY_STRING") or "Anonymous"
    if query_string:
      username = query_string.split("username=")[1].split("&")[0]
      await sio.save_session(sid, {'username': username})
      room_name = await change_group_name(username)
      sio.enter_room(sid, room_name)
    print(f"[Connected] {sid}")
  except Exception as e:
    print("Connected error", str(e))
@sio.on("login")
async def handle_login(sid, data):
  username = data.get("username")
  session_id = await sio.get_session(sid)
  connected_users[sid] = {"username": username, "session_id": session_id['username']}
  print(f"{username} logged in.")
@sio.on("disconnect")
async def disconnect(sid):
  try:
    username = connected_users.get(sid, {}).get("username", "Anonymous")
    connected_users.pop(sid, None)
    leave_room = await change_group_name(username)
    sio.leave_room(sid, leave_room)
    print(f"Disconnected: {sid}, Username: {username}")
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"Disconnected Error: {e}")
@sio.on("client_chat_app")
async def message_from_client(sid, data):
  username = connected_users.get(sid, {}).get("username", "Anonymous")
  user = await get_user_obj(username)
  await chat_app_function(data, user, sid)
```

Client-side code:

```js
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
useEffect(() => {
  let username = “username”;
  socket = socketIOClient(WEB_SOCKET_IO, {
   query: { username: username },
   secure: true,
   transports: ["websocket"],
   path: "/socket.io/",
   reconnectionDelay: 1000,
   reconnection: true,
   reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
  });
  socket.on("connect", () => {
   socket.emit("login", { username });
  });
  let event_chat_app = username + "sent_chat_app";
  socket.on(event_chat_app, (value) => {
   try {
    console.log(“value”, value)
   } catch (e) {}
  });
 }
 return () => {
  socket?.disconnect();
 };
}, []);
```